# $A$, $B$, $C$ do a job $6$ hours faster than $A$ alone, $1$ hour faster than $B$ alone, and in half the time needed by $C$ alone. ...

Tags: arithmetic

> Three men $A$, $B$, $C$ working together can do a job in $6$ hours less time than $A$ alone, in $1$ hour less time than $B$ alone, and in one-half the time needed by $C$ when working alone. Then $A$ and $B$ together can do the job in how many hours?

Could we solve this without a quadratic equation?

Comment: If you know how to solve the problem *with* a quadratic equation, you should include that in your question. That'll save readers some time and effort in seeking an alternative approach

Comment: Not really.  Dealing with rates of time and sharing work loads makes for an equation in which one must solve for variables in the reciprical. An the only way to solve those is to invert by multiplying by a common multiple of the denominaters.  As the denominaters has a linear combination of variable, the common multiple will be a quadratic.

Comment: @user160370 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I did some search over google and found this. They have used minimal steps. But, I couldn't understand most of it. [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible without a qudratic equation, here is my solution.

Let's indicate with 100 the work to be done and with $x,y,z$ the productivity for A,B,C.

We know that

$$\frac{100}{x+y+z}=\frac{100}x-6 \implies100x=100(x+y+z)-6x(x+y+z)$$

$$\frac{100}{x+y+z}=\frac{100}y-1\implies100y=100(x+y+z)-y(x+y+z)$$

$$\frac{100}{x+y+z}=\frac12\frac{100}z\implies z=x+y$$

then summing up the two first equations we obtain

$$100z=400z-(5x+z)(2z)\implies5x+z=150 \implies z=150-5x$$

and from the first one

$$100x=200z-12xz \implies100x=30000-1000x-1800x+60x^2 $$

$$\implies 3x^2-145x+1500=0$$

$$\implies x=15 \implies z=75 \implies y=60$$

Thus $A$ and $B$ working togheter need $\frac{100}{75}=\frac{4}{3}$h to complete the work.

Comment: @gmusi: the quadratic equation has two roots, why did you pick $15$?

Comment: @Vasya The other one (100/3) gives a negative value for $z$.

Comment: A and B working toghether $= \frac {100}{x+y} = \frac {100}{75} = \frac {4}{3}$ hours.

Comment: @DougM Ops...yes I summed up A and C...thanks I fix

Comment: Oh, how many times have I done great work right up to the last step and then lost my focus.